# Javascript analogy for powershell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: jquery, powershell, authentication

How to translate the following PowerShell request to javascript/jQuery?

```
$spass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$pass
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://mydomain/api/test" -Credential $cred
```

I tried the following ajax call but this doesn't prevent me from standard browser auth popup which ask for username and password:

```
$.ajax({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')
    },
    url: "https://mydomain",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data){
             console.log(data);
            }
});
```

Same result if I paste the following url in to the browser `http://username:password@mydomain` this also redirects to the standard auth popup.

Comment: The Windows PowerShell versions of `Invoke-RestMethod`/`Invoke-WebRequest` defers to the `HttpWebRequest` .NET class, which will attempt NTLM/Kerberos/Basic auth - so if it works with `Invoke-RestMethod`, but not when you manually add a `Basic` authorization header, then that probably means your API doesn't support basic authentication :)

Comment: True, but how to provide keroberos credential in jQuery?